# Go to page and reload Javascript/Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a small wizard. After submitting the form I have created a button to start a new.

The issue is that I need the cache clear since I'm using UI-router to call different pages and then having a form controller to check if each page (or step) is valid. I can't do a simple

```
window.location.reload(true);
```

Because the controller would then just return a blank page. If I do

```
window.location.href = '#/form/start';
```

The cache isn't cleared and the user is able to bypass the safe guards.

I've tried using them both but the cache is still there;

```
    $scope.beginNew = function() {
    window.location.reload(true);
    window.location.href = '#/form/start';
};
```

What can I do to go to a page then issue a reload?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `cache: false` to your `app.js` or wherever you are adding your states, for example:

```
.state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        cache: false,
        templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
        controller: 'HomeCtrl'
    })
```

Comment: Wouldn't that disable the cache entirely? I'd like to just clear it after the user has clicked a restart button with ng-click

Comment: I don't think there is, or at least I'm not familiar with a way to reload the page when using `ui-router`. Also not exactly sure what you're doing in your app, but if you set your states to `cache: false`, then yes it would disable cache entirely for that state. But if you're using services, this wouldn't be an issue. Every time you navigate to a different state, the controller would be re-initialized with data from a service, but the data in the service would remain the same. So you could 'reset' the values in your service when you click `beginNew()`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly if there's any redundancy in this code but after some trial and error this seemed to work;

Add $window to the controller.

And then this;

```
    $scope.beginNew = function() {
    $scope.formData = {};
    window.location.href = '#/form/test';
    $window.location.reload();
    $state.reload();
};
```

$state.reload might be redundant or $window.location.reload(); might be.

Comment: I think `$state.reload()` is redundant.